# Define Variable type dynamically in stored procedures in DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, variable-assignment

Is it possible to define the type of a variable in a stored procedure dynamically with the type of a column in a table..

I want to set the type of `myVar` the type of mytable.mycolumn

```
DECLARE at_end SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE myVar VARCHAR(21); -- It should be the type of mytable.mycolumn
```

In Oracle it would be possible with `age_of_person mytable.mycolumn%TYPE;`

How does it work in DB2 9.7??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
DECLARE myVar ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO mytable.mycolumn;
```

Another way is to enable Oracle commands in DB2. It makes possible to use PL-SQL Syntax (i.e. `%TYPE` keyword) like in oracle